# Creating Dataframe from inconsistently named columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that has redundant column names due to the files(.csv) having inconsistent naming. This is resulting in columns with mostly NaN values

```
Bike #  Bikenumber  Bike#   SubscriberType  SubscriptionType
 NaN       NaN     W20848      NaN             Subscriber
 NaN       NaN     W20231      NaN             Subscriber
 NaN       NaN     W00785      NaN             Subscriber
 NaN       NaN     W00126      NaN             Subscriber
 NaN       NaN     W20929      NaN             Casual
```

Is there a way to create a new column and populate it from multiple columns that have values? And if more than one column is not `NaN`, can i select which column to pull the value from?

```
 Bike#   Bikenumber   Bike #   Selected_Num
number1   number2      NaN       number2
```

I can get this when trying to fill with a single column

```
sample['Bike_Num'] = sample['Bike #'].fillna(sample['Bike#'])
print(sample)

    Bike #  Bikenumber  Bike#   SubscriberType  SubscriptionType   Bike_Num
     NaN       NaN     W20848      NaN             Subscriber       W20848
     NaN       NaN     W20231      NaN             Subscriber       W20231
     NaN       NaN     W00785      NaN             Subscriber       W00785
     NaN       NaN     W00126      NaN             Subscriber       W00126
     NaN       NaN     W20929      NaN             Casual           W20929
```

This fails for

```
sample['Bike_Num'] = sample['Bike #'].fillna(sample['Bike#'], sample['Bikenumber'])

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to clean the data at the time is was read from the csv?  How is the data being read from the csv file?

Comment: @StephenRauch: There are ~20 csv files that I'm reading in from the directory with a `for` loop and concatenating them with `total_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index = True)`.

Comment: You are using `pandas.read_csv`?  Also am I right to understand that you basically have some lists of synonyms for column names?

Comment: @StephenRauch that's correct I'm using `pandas.read_csv` and yes, the column names are synonymous but they are named slightly differently. I.E. `Bike# = Bike # = Bikenumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you solve this at the time of reading in the CSV's instead of trying to untangle them later.  One way to do that is to use a small parser for the CSV files before passing them to `pandas`.

This parser takes an open file handle to the `csv`, and a dict which maps the desired column names to the various possible synonyms.

**Code:**

```
def read_my_csv(file_handle, column_map):
    # reverse the column mapping dict to use for synonym lookup
    synoms = dict(sum([
        [(syn, k) for syn in v] for k, v in column_map.items()], []))

    # build csv reader
    reader = csv.reader(file_handle)

    # get the header, and map columns to desired names
    header = next(reader)
    header = [synoms.get(c, c) for c in header]

    # yield the header
    yield header

    # yield the remaining rows
    for row in reader:
        yield row
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

column_map = {
    'Bike_Num': ('Bike #', 'Bikenumber', 'Bike#'),
    'Sub_Num': ('SubscriberType', 'SubscriptionType'),
}

with open("sample.csv", 'rU') as f:
    generator = read_my_csv(f, column_map)
    columns = next(generator)
    df = pd.DataFrame(generator, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

**Sample.csv:**

```
Bike #,SubscriptionType
W20848,Subscriber
W20231,Subscriber
W00785,Subscriber
W00126,Subscriber
W20929,Casual
```

**Results:**

```
  Bike_Num     Sub_Num
0   W20848  Subscriber
1   W20231  Subscriber
2   W00785  Subscriber
3   W00126  Subscriber
4   W20929      Casual
```

**Solution #2**

A cleaner, but not nearly as fun, solution is to rename the columns before doing the concat:

**Code:**

```
def fix_column_names(df, column_map):
    # reverse the column mapping dict to use for synonym lookup
    synoms = dict(sum([
        [(syn, k) for syn in v] for k, v in column_map.items()], []))

    # rename columns
    df.columns = [synoms.get(c, c) for c in df.columns]
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

column_map = {
    'Bike_Num': ('Bike #', 'Bikenumber', 'Bike#'),
    'Sub_Num': ('SubscriberType', 'SubscriptionType'),
}

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=0)
fix_column_names(df, column_map)
print(df)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! I'm still newish to python and this is an approach that I hadn't considered. Love it! :)